# Constant Current, 1.5 amp, high voltage into variable load

Tags: high-voltage, constant-current

I need to design a constant current 1.5 A circuit.

Input:  A 3.3 v, 3 mA, 1.5 millisec pulse.

Load: Detonators, with total resistance starting at 80 ohms and increases to 160 ohms in 1.5 ms.  Current must be continuous (NOT PWM).

Output: Current can vary between 1.4 to 1.6 A, ideally 1.5A.

Environment: Temperature varies between between 0 to 150 deg F

Max V required is V = 1.5 A * 160 ohm = 240 V.

240 V is too high for Constant Current (CC) IC's.  High volt BJT's & MOSFETs are very difficult to control at "low" 1.5 A current.  I can select a power supply of any voltage needed.  Has anyone else did CC with high current AND high v, pulsed for short time?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd spend a bit more time trying to properly describe what you are trying to achieve then edit your question so it is more accessible to readers. Nobody cares about the 8 days you spent BUT most folk will care if you spent another ten minutes sorting this question into something that is meaningful.

Comment: Please use paragraphs to break the text into logical sections. Explain what the load is, why you think you need constant current and what temperature has to do with it. "V" or "volt", "A" or "amp". Capitals matter.

Comment: " I can't have **voltage** transients outside my 1.4 - 1.6 **Amp** range." Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The question is improving. Does this need a linear current or can it accept PWM? Again, what is the load?

Comment: So you're building a bomb detonator that works from a coin cell battery that you can hide in a suitcase? :P

Comment: If you want CC then what is the 1.5 ms all about? You said "continuous" and this also seems to be at odds with the 1.5 ms pulse thing. Why don't you phrase your question like "I want to be able to supply 1.5 amps to a load that has a resistance up to 160 ohms for (say) 1.5 ms" - is this what you want?

Comment: @Andyaka Because apparently after 1.5ms there is no more load.... lol  =-D

Comment: @Tyler that question is for the OP \$LOL^2\$

Comment: If the load can float something like this.. (but with different parts/ values.) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62564/op-amps-with-output-on-n-channel-mosfet

Comment: I have built CC supplies with +1500VDC output using a UC3844 IC and a custom transformer, but I am reluctant to do a diagram for this problem. George Herold has a plausible solution. It only has to work once...

Comment: George Herold's link showing an op-amp can't be used because they are not rated for 200 to 300 V.  I'm NOT building a bomb, I am TESTING detonators and the circuit should last for decades.  I need an output pulse that goes from zero current to 1.5 A in < i microsec, stays 1.5 A regradless of load (80 to 160 ohm), and decreases to zero A in < 1 us.  This requires a circuit of transistors or mosfets to achieve fast switching.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsQCDH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Detonator circuit.*

An overdamped LCR circuit might work for you. This setup, according to my calculations, would raise the current to 1.6 A in 0.2 ms, falling to 1.2 A after 1.5 ms with detonator resistance rising from 80 to 160 ohms.

L1 internal resistance and R1 should sum to 100 ohms. Detonator power dissipation would peak at 500 W, falling to 400 W.

Update

An overdamped RLC circuit (\$ R^2 > \frac {4L}{C} \$) current at time (t) is given by

$$ i(t) = \frac {V_0}{\omega _0L}e^{\frac {-R}{2L}t} sinh~\omega _0t$$

where

$$ \omega _0  = \sqrt {(\frac {R}{2L})^2 - \frac {1}{LC} } $$

[image]

I calculated the information here using a spreadsheet and I'm not that confident of my results. I would appreciate if some could post a link for a simulation of the circuit to show if my results look reasonable.

Comment: Current decays to 0.4 A (not 1.4 A) in LTSPICE simulation of discharging the cap into a 80 to 160 ohm load.

Comment: The circuit must work with a load that can vary such as: R = 80, or R = 80 to 120, or 80 to 160 in 1.5 ms.  Please replace the ideal switches with transistor or mosfets that can accept a pulse coming as input.  The circuit must adapt to changing loads by keeping current at 1.5 amps regardless of whether R = 80, or R = 120, R = 160, or R varies with time from 80 to 160 ohms.

Comment: Ehm, that's coming across a little bit demanding, Don. I'm volunteering my time on this.

Comment: Sorry.  Constant current examples using Widlar etc rely on transistor or mosfet curves where collector (or drain) current stays constant as Vce or Vds vary.  However, this isn't the case for 1.5 A and a high source of ~250 or 300V.

Comment: I need an output pulse that goes from zero current to 1.5 A in < i microsec, stays 1.5 A regardless of load (any value between 80 to 160 ohm), and decreases to zero A in < 1 us. This requires a circuit of transistors or mosfets to achieve fast switching